# C# Key action while process in background

Tags: c#

I made a Form and added a few buttons. 
But instead want to press ctrl+NumpadKey1 to do exactly what the buttons would do.
Thus I need to access the program while it's in the background.

Does anyone have any ideas?
I already got the code for when the form is in the front.

Comment: Please, edit or delete before you have been down voted.

Comment: I'll delete if the problem is solved, if not I'll edit it, thanks @RustamUmarov

Answer (score 1):

Try using global hooks. [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/) explain how to do this. In short you have to set up hook:

```
[DllImport(“user32.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
```

On the end you have to unhook:

```
[DllImport(“user32.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
```

And this is how you can create handler:

```
private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;

private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```